# LINQ OrderByDescending to OrderByAscending?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert the following LINQ statement to OrderByAscending instead of OrderByDescending?  There are for some reason no OrderByAscending:

```
            var unProfParameterSets = RawAARdDDArray1
               .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
               .OrderByDescending(item => item.value)
               .Take(unProfParams)
               .Select(item => RawParamSet[item.index])
               .ToArray();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method to order results in accending order is `OrderBy`

```
 var unProfParameterSets = RawAARdDDArray1
           .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
           .OrderBy(item => item.value)
           .Take(unProfParams)
           .Select(item => RawParamSet[item.index])
           .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Game CheapestGame(List<Game> games)
{
    var lowestPrice = new Game();

    lowestPrice = games.OrderBy(c => c.Price).First();

    return lowestPrice;
}
```